# Percentiles on prometheus counter increase

Tags: prometheus

I have a prometheus counter containing CPU usage seconds ( container_cpu_usage_seconds ).
How can I get the 99th percentile of the counter increase?

I tried

```
    irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="cc-backend", container="cc-backend"}[14d] ) 
)by (pod, container)
```

but *irate* only returns 1 value for each element, so the *quantile* function doesn't help me in that case. I need some kind of function that calculates the difference between each counter entry.

Comment: The metric you are trying to use is a simple counter, it won't work with `histogram_quantile()` which requires buckets with `le` labels on them. I think this might be the [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/); what are you going to do with the quantile?

Comment: I want to know the 99th percentile of my CPU usage so I can scale accordingly